# Extracting all intersections from polyline shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, intersection, address

I would like to extract all the intersections from a polyline shapefile and print their addresses as text using QGIS.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

My polyline has address information.

It is a "roads" file, and I don't need to compare it to other layers.

Comment: Does your polyline contain address information? or do need to do a 'near' on another layer?

Comment: Why don't you use the existing tags instead of creating new ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS has a 'line intersections' tool that will create a point at all intersections.

I'm not sure about getting an address at the intersection--I see a few issues with that.

1. Which road would you pick to pull the address from?
2. Since intersections generally don't *have* addresses, is it even meaningful? I realize that a single line street network with ranges will 'have' an address at all points, but it is not necessarily meaningful. (This goes with Mapperz question; do you really want the *closest* address?)

Comment: well I was thinking it would say like "1st ave and 3rd st" or something like that.

Comment: @iterationx - did you try the QGIS Line Intersections tool? That's exactly what it will do. It will put the two names in separate columns, but you could concatenate them as a second step.

Comment: I will try it soon.

Answer (score -3):

The intersection also gives the streets ID in the derived Info.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Your answer is very vague. When answering questions, try to be as detailed as possible, otherwise it won't help the person asking.