# Extracting Total Block Count or Intersections for given city or list of cities?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, intersection, road, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am currently trying to count the total number of blocks in a given city without manually counting them by hand.

Is there a way to query the total count of **block numbers**  in some programming language ( I think ArcGIS uses Python) for a given city or list of cities ,so that the output would be as below

```
    City      Total Number of Blocks
Manhattan      12563
```

Or even more granular per city from list.

> City = Manhattan

```
Block#      GPS Coordinates  
1           56.6767,79.485748           
...         ....
12456       56.6754,79.476776
```

In this photo from ArcGIS, which is a screenshot of a map of Manhattan, it outputs the **the address number of each block .**

[image: Numbered Block Number]

You should be able to see **the numbers** **"54" Chambers Street** , **"68"** , **"270"**, **"35"**

I have looked at this past question that was asked 3 years ago, but was unable to solve it with their recommendations.
[Counting road intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/counting-road-intersections-and-blocks)
["Extracting all intersections from polyline shapefile using QGIS? "](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29047/extracting-all-intersections-from-polyline-shapefile-using-qgis)

I am **not an expert at all**.

I am using a trial license of ArcGIS Desktop.

---

## Vector Dataset Update Per @FelixIP

I have found a website that allows me to get a vectorized dataset [BBBIKE](http://extract.bbbike.org/)

[image: Manhattan Vector Data]

### Supported Output Formats for BBbike

[image: Supported_Formats_For_BBbike]
 - They have a "pro version" which allows one to get metadata associated with the "extract"

Comment: +1 for efforts, don't rush to programming, because what you are trying to achieve is doable using basic tools, providing you have necessary inputs

Comment: @FelixIP Which basic tools do you speak of?

Comment: Depending on inputs this could be intersect or spatial join or near tool

Comment: @FelixIP What do you mean by "inputs"? I am sorry if that sounds like a stupid question, but are you referring to these http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm as "inputs."

Comment: What you have on your map are background layers, perhaps great for mapping, but useless for real analysis. You cannot derive anything new. Search for downloadable Vector datasets from council or government web sites or other data providers.

Comment: @FelixIP  I searched for a vector dataset and came across this [BBBike](http://extract.bbbike.org/). Is this what you mean by a "downloadable Vector datasets? " Please check out my update, when you can.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing as the "total number of blocks labeled" appear to actually be street address numbers at the beginning and end of each block.

Comment: "The world transportation map layer already has the total number of blocks labeled, I think?!?!, if that is correct?" I never said that they were, I said that I thought they were, but ending up looking like a complete idiot...

Comment: Sorry, whenever I try to answer a question, I home in on the question mark that should indicate the question being asked.  The many headings in your question had me looking straight past them to the text beneath so I think your question would be clearer without most/all of them.

Comment: Not a problem at all. You have been doing this a lot longer than I have. I will gladly edit it, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! How should I rephrase my question, so that I am able to make it easier for someone to help?